# Converting md5 hash to bigint in python

Tags: python, postgresql, hash, biginteger

In postgres, I am using this function to convert a md5 hash to bigint:

```sql
SELECT ('x'||substr(md5('text'),1,16))::bit(64)::bigint;
```

I was able to make it work for positive integer values:

```py
import hashlib

def string2numeric_hash(text):
    return int(hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest()[0:16], 16)
```

But for negative values I am getting wrong results

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we get example data?

Comment: What do you mean by negative values? A string of hex digits unambiguously corresponds to an unsigned integer (in the mathematical sense, not necessarily or, here, realistically the native `int` type).

Answer (score 1):

Using `int(..., 16)` conversion is not going to know or assume anything about negative values, because that would require assuming some particular machine representation of integers, such as using two's complement to represent negative values.

Your postgres query works because you're explicitly converting the value to a 64-bit signed integer.

There are a few ways you could get the result you want.  One is to use the [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) method.  First to convert your hex string to bytes:

```py
b = bytes.fromhex(hash)
```

then use `int.from_bytes`--assuming you want little-endian and signed bytes:

```py
int.from_bytes(b, 'little', signed=True)
```

Full example:

```py
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(hashlib.md5(b'StackOverflow').hexdigest()[:16]), 'little', signed=True)
8017652491122169732
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(hashlib.md5(b'StackOverflow Rules').hexdigest()[:16]), 'little', signed=True)
-4954873531347136310
```

Or, as others rightfully pointed out in the comments you could simply skip a step and use `md5.digest()` instead:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(hashlib.md5(b'StackOverflow Rules').digest()[:8], 'little', signed=True)
-4954873531347136310
```

Here you are also not necessarily restricted to 64-bit ints, so you don't necessarily have to truncate to 16 hex digits unless you want the exact same results as the other code.

Comment: Maybe one could simplify `int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(<md5>.hexdigest()), ...)` to `int.from_bytes(<md5>.digest(), ...)`? I.e. instead of telling MD5 to produce hex, and then interpreting that hex, work with digest as raw bytes to begin with.

Comment: Did you actually get that last result or did you copy that? Using bytes should require `[:8]` to get that.